# Shiny large plots overlap

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I'm producing some pretty big plots (a grid of about 100 bar graphs). I use verticallayout with the default of `fluid = TRUE`. I have the size set in my server function
`output$hist7 <- renderPlot({ #actual plot excluded though any will do
}, height=1000, width=800)`

When I try to place text below this plot with `h1("text here")`, 
"text here" ends up in the middle of hist7. This issue does not occur with any of the plots I didn't set the size for, this is the only one large enough that I have to set a size to prevent shiny scaling it down

Answer (score 4):

The fix should be

ui.R

```
plotOutput(outputId = 'plot2', width = "700px", height = "600px")
```

server.R

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(...) + geom_bar(stat="identity", ...)
    p
  }, width = 700, height = 600)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had success using `inline=TRUE` argument in `plotOutput` and then adding a `br()` between the plot and my text. E.g.,

```
column(
    plotOutput("my.plot", inline = TRUE), 
    br(),
    h1("my text here")
)
```

Answer (score -3):

The trick is specifying the same plot size in the ui: `plotOutput("hist6", height=1000, width=800)`